# Can Mozilla Rhino detect and report if it is making calls to Deprecated Java methods?

Tags: java, javascript, deprecated, rhino, mirth

Can Mozilla Rhino detect and report if it is making calls to deprecated Java methods?

I am using Mirth Connect, which uses Rhino, to call Java methods. I know that I have a Java library which has recently deprecated several methods. Can I somehow have Rhino report or warn if it is calling a deprecated method?

We are using the `@Deprecated` annotation to indicate which methods are deprecated.

My hope here is that Rhino can detect this, without any need for the user to call some helper method to inspect their code, and then log or report on it. The use-case is that if we deprecate methods now, most of our users use those methods from Rhino and will never see deprecation warnings. So that when the methods are finally removed, *then* the user will get hard `NoSuchMethod` exceptions which is not really a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the libraries used the 'new' @Deprecated annotation to deprecate their methods, then the information would be carried into runtime that the method has been deprecated, and then Rhino *could* detect that if it cared to. I don't think Rhino does this though. It shouldn't be too hard to grab the source and check if it does.

If the libraries used the older method of deprecating methods (via javadoc), then I don't think it would even be possible.

Comment: Javac checks at compile-time, and it warns (verbose with -Xlint:deprecated). Rhino just checks the JS syntax, so you *would* have to use the reflection API to check at runtime (as @Bill states)